# Do I have to get rid of my release statements upon upgrading to ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

New to all this ARC stuff.

I've been developing an iOS game using Manual Reference Counting with `cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1` this whole time.

Recently, upon reading some instructions (http://www.tinytimgames.com/2011/07/22/cocos2d-and-arc/#comment-563567859), I upgraded my project to support Automatic Reference Counting.

When I developed using the manual method, I, of course, used `release` in many places. However, I noticed that I had many memory leaks and I was having a hard time finding all of them - thus I changed to ARC.

However, I wonder, do I have to erase my `[object release];` statements for ARC to work properly? Or it doesn't matter and I really don't have to do any kind of change at all?

If I used `[object retain];` and `[object release];`, do I get rid of the former and assume that ARC will take care of releasing it? Or do I still have the responsibility of releasing manually it since I explicitly took ownership of the object?

Comment: If your MRC code is already leaking, expect the conversion to ARC to cause crashes and bugs. Converting to ARC won't magically fix these things, instead they'll come about as different kinds of errors. Finding and fixing them sometimes requires a deeper understanding of how ARC works behind the scenes, so be prepared to read up ... no, actually just post more questions here. :)

Answer (score 3):

NO need to manually do all these stuffs.

You should **refactor** your code. [Check here How to Refactor to ARC.](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/10/24/migration-to-arc-automatic-reference-counting-using-xcode-4-2-refactor/)

Also [How do I convert my Xcode project to use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780412/how-do-i-convert-my-xcode-project-to-use-arc-automatic-reference-counting)

Comment: Thank you, I am following that refactor guide. However, I am having problems. It says that Xcode will find X amount of errors I need to fix (in my case, I have 178 errors, although Xcode said 5051). The guide tells me to fix them using the suggestion thing, but I'm afraid I don't seem to be able to use such function (it does not appear for some reason). What do you recommend?

Comment: Ok actually, I do see the suggestion thing, but only for warnings. What do I do with the actual errors?

Comment: You can fix quite easily, but make a backup and then start refactoring.  and all fixing situations can be find in google and SO.

Comment: I see, so when Xcode gives a suggestion, I use it, and when it does not, I search the error on Google? Ok, I'll try it and let you know how it goes. In a couple hours XD...

Answer (score 2):

Calling `retain` or `release` is an error when you're using ARC, it won't even compile.