# ARC related Issue.retain an array and release service

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am new in using `ARC`.
I am struggling how to `release a service` or `retain an array` without giving `retain` or `release` as `ARC` is `Yes`.even i cant Switch it to `No`.Because other functions in same class using `ARC`.

My doubts are:

`[arrayValues retain];`

`[service release];`

`service = [serviceValue retain];`

How can I change these to ARC-compatible code?

Comment: You don't. You let the compiler do its job.

Comment: are you trying to port some pre-ARC code or what?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170655/do-i-have-to-get-rid-of-my-release-statements-upon-upgrading-to-arc?rq=1

Comment: @H2CO3 - then can i leave it blank or comment those lines in code ?

Comment: Check out "Xcode => Edit => Refactor => Convert to Obj-ARC" ...

Comment: @DigiMonk's comment is what you're looking for. He should add it as an answer (perhaps with some explanation of what it does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable ARC on MULTIPLE files:

```
Select desired files at Target/Build Phases/Compile Sources in Xcode

PRESS ENTER

Type -fno-objc-arc

Press Enter or Done
```

Comment: in that same class i am using functions which is based on ARC.so i am not able to do that.any other way ?

Comment: anyOther way to release or retain ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: no its not possible either you can use ARC or not. he have to convert your code

Comment: no there is no other way to use release or retain you have to turn off ARC to use this.

Comment: There is no need to retain/release under ARC.  That is the whole point of the ARC feature.  This answer is misleading;  unless you have an explicit requirement to *not* use ARC (and you don't, as far as your question is concerned), there is no reason to turn ARC off for some subset of files.  In fact, that'll just lead to confusion and fragility in that you'll have to remember which files are ARC'd or not.